# Creating new control in form builder

Tags: orbeon

I cannot find a way to create a new control with custom behavior in the Orbeon Forms documentation. Does anyone know how to create one?

All I can do at the moment is create a new entry in the *Text Controls* panel, but whatever I put in configuration of the `<templates><view>` of the control that is not an already implemented control results in validation/parser exception.

Comment: I am not clear on what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to create a new XBL control? Did you get a chance already to go through the [XBL Tutorial](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/xbl/tutorial.html)?

Comment: I am trying to create a new XBL control that will be placed in the Text Controls panel. It has to add a section to the form which will consist of one text input and one boolean type with custom login in separate .js file. The tutorial didn't really help me on this.

Comment: Currently, XBL can only be used to add controls, not sections. But maybe the [section templates](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/section-templates.html) would do what you're looking for?

Comment: So you say that i cant create a XBL control, that instead of adding one input to the form adds two? The only solution is to create a section template just like US Address in the docs?

Comment: An XBL control can have multiple fields (like, say, the fields date, which has 3 input fields for the day, month, and year), but it will always take the space of 1 control in a grid, which may or may not be what you want. If what you want to do is more like a "block of controls", then using a section template is the way to go.

Comment: what i want is a control with multiple fields but takes space of 1 control just like you say. The thing is that those inputs have to be of different type.

Comment: Got it, then XBL is the way to go. Do you want to combine what the user enters in the fields in 1 value, like you would when you have multiple fields to enter a date, or doe the values for each field need to be store separately?

Comment: I want separate values. First input is a default non-resizeable string input. The second one is clickable small image, which will run custom JS function. The third one is a boolean checkbox, which will enable/disable inputs above.

Comment: So in your XBL, in the Form Builder metadata, in `<templates>`, you'll want to provide an `<instance>` with the additional attributes or elements to store the values you need. For instance, see `attachment.xbl`. And of course, just let ohs know if you're blocked at any point.

Comment: Ive managed to separate my inputs. I have one string input and a output, which is an image underneath. Then i have checkbox. My problem is: How can i force the image to be on the right of the input, and not under it, Secondly, how can i run custom javascript on image click, Lastly, how can i disable those inputs based on checkbox value?

Comment: I am not sure I can really answer those questions here, but I can maybe give you some pointers. For layout, it is most likely a CSS question. To hookup your own JavaScript, you can find some inspiration in existing controls, say the [JavaScript companion for the number control](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/form-runner/jvm/src/main/assets/xbl/orbeon/number/number.js). Regarding disabling an input based on a checkbox, is the checkbox inside the control?

Comment: yes it is inside the control

Comment: Got it, then you should be able to bind those controls to a local instance, and use `<xf:bind relevant=“…”>` on that instance. See for instance `wpaint.xbl`: it doesn’t use a `<xf:bind>` on a local instance, but uses a local instance with mirroring, which is maybe the most tricky part to put in place.